# Concatenate Error while adding date format to existing file path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

**Hello stackflowers, I'm  newbee here and i need help**

*I been recently learning pandas library in python and trying to automate the output file, I was successful with it. But when i thought of adding date to the output path the error i'm facing is "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"*

**Can anyone help me on this...**

```
#saving in a path

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
t = timestamp.year, timestamp.month, timestamp.day

path = r'C:\Users\Revanth\Desktop\pandas_tutorials\New_Idle_Artist_List.xlsx'

split_filename = path.split(".")
exportpath = os.rename(path, split_filename[:-1]+'-'+join(t))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(exportpath,engine='xlsxwriter',datetime_format='mmm d yyyy')




**Error displayed** : runfile('C:/Users/Revanth/.spyder-py3/Idle_artist_appliction.py', wdir='C:/Users/Revanth/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Revanth\.spyder-py3\Idle_artist_appliction.py", line 71, in <module>
    exportpath = os.rename(path, [split_filename[:-1]+'-'+join(t)])

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Have a look at the `pathlib` module from the standard lib for proper handling of paths and filenames in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of my comment, how you could construct the exportpath using the `Path` class from the `pathlib` module. It might look complicated at first sight but will pay off on the long run since very convenient once you get used to it.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\Users\Revanth\Desktop\pandas_tutorials\New_Idle_Artist_List.xlsx')

datestring = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# e.g. '2020-06-28'

exportpath = path.parent/f'{path.stem}-{datestring}{path.suffix}'
# e.g. WindowsPath('C:/Users/Revanth/Desktop/pandas_tutorials/New_Idle_Artist_List-2020-06-28.xlsx')
```

- First, we make a Path object from the path string (raw string mode since we have single backslashes)
- Construct today's year-month-day string using `strftime`
- Make the exportpath. `path.parent` is everything except filename. Then we can use a `/` to combine that with a new filename which we construct using an `f-string`. `path.stem` is the filename without its extension; `path.suffix` is *only* the extension.

Refs: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)